# How can I check if the hide button pf iPad's keyboard was pressed?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, hide

I want to trigger a function that will depend on which method the user used to resign a textField's first responder. If it was resigned by selecting another textField, it does nothing, else triggers a function. Is this possible?

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you can post it as an answer yourself and accept it rather than editing it into your question (although that's okay too).

Comment: Thanks for this. I used it to dismiss a UISearchBar shown in the main view of a UISplitViewController when the user taps on the detail view, or when they use the keyboard dismiss view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how. You just have to listen to the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodYouWantToCall) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)methodYouWantToCall {

    //Do anything you want here
```

}